# Adding event callback for YouTube JS Player API when related video clicked

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

YouTube's [iFrame embed JS player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Adding_event_listener)  allows you to add callbacks to certain events. I want to add a callback for when a related video at the end of a video is selected.

To be more specific, when viewing a video in an embed, at the end it displays related videos within the embed. I want to run some code when one of those is selected. How can this be accomplished? I see that there is an onStateChange but none of the states are related to related videos. Do I need to add an onStateChange for YT.PlayerState.PLAYING and then compare the playing video to the original video to see if they're different somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it basically the way I described. Here's the code I used:

```
started = false;

var onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(id) {
  var player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: id,
    events: {
      'onStateChange': function (event) {
        if (event.data == 1) { // The video started playing
          started = true;
        }
        if (started && event.data == -1) {
          // Video had already started playing before and is now in
          // "unstarted" state so it must be a new video.
          var video_url = event.target.i.videoUrl;
          var video_id = video_url.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '').replace('&feature=player_embedded', '');
          window.location = '#/view/' + video_id;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

So basically, when a video starts playing, you set a "started" variable to true. Then, if/when the video enters the "unstarted" state, if "started" is true, then you know that it's a new video that just started playing. In that case, grab its video ID from the event.target object and do whatever you want with it.

My full commit is [here](https://github.com/mikecrittenden/toogles/commit/9ac2b951414b25ad96777b90d19962d45162593e) if anyone wants to see the context and you can see it in action on http://toogl.es.

Comment: oh cool; you're the guy who created toogl.es. saw that on HN. I commented with a tip about implementing auto-complete via the youtube suggestion search API.. it's really straight forward with the bootstrap autocomplete plugin -- it'd be nice to have that functionality there.

Comment: Just gave you the bounty, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I remember your comment--autocomplete is on my short list of todos. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a reasonable solution to me.

The only point worth mentioning (which you've noted) is that you will be *not* able to tell if the change in the video is due to the user *clicking on a related video*, but if you're not interacting with the player dynamically, comparing the previous VideoID should suffice.

Just a heads up, if you're interested in a jQuery plugin that simplifies some of the callback/event handling work check out: https://github.com/nirvanatikku/jQuery-TubePlayer-Plugin